# What is a "reference edge" in TensorBoard?

Tags: graph, tensorflow, tensorboard

The TensorBoard UI shows something called a "Reference edge" as distinct from a data flow (`Tensor`) edge:

[image]

What distinguishes the former from the latter?

The documentation says that "the outgoing operation node can mutate the incoming tensor", but indicates different symbols that don't match the UI, so it's hard to tell what's meant by "incoming" and "outgoing":

[image]

For example how does this definition apply to

```
cs = tf.constant([1,2,3], name='const_share')
vs = tf.Variable([1,2,3], name='var_share')
tf.add(cs, vs, name='opVS1')
tf.add(vs, cs, name='opVS2')
```

[image]

or to

```
tf.add([4],[3], name='opA')
```

[image]

In both cases it just seems that the reference edge indicates that the value its tail fills the `Tensor` represented by the edge.

Comment: I must say that I don't see the point of those illustrations. To me, at least, they are far less clear than the corresponding definition code.

Comment: @MaxB For large graphs they can be indispensable, especially in the early design phases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a source of confusion, [even to DeepMind developers](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10428#issuecomment-306056805) and is being [fixed in future releases](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10428#issuecomment-306392998) so that:

1. All reference edges will be a distinct color (and dataflow edges the
   same grey as before).
2. Arrows to all dataflow edges no matter where
   they point (instead of only appearing in cases where data flowed
   "downward").

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I do not see any reference edges on your graph, but here is how you can easily get one:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.Variable(1, name="a")
b = a.assign_add(2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.summary.FileWriter('logs', sess.graph)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

When you will click on `a` and remove it from the main graph you will see a reference edge:

[image]

In TF there are no [bidirectional edges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirected_graph) during the runtime. But there are some operations (like [`tf.assign_add`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign_add)) which return the same value as one of the input by modifying it:

> ref: A mutable Tensor

So TF adds a reference edge where the operation reads the previous value, does something and rewrite it with the new value. The analogy is most probably with pointers/references. So the doc kind of makes sense:

> A reference edge showing that the outgoing operation node can mutate
>   the incoming tensor.

Comment: "I do not see any reference edges on your graph": So the key in the UI is wrong (and the key in the docs is right)? Then it all makes sense, actually.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I can't say for sure. But I always thought that a bidirectional edge `<->` is the reference edge.

Comment: Yeah, I think the docs are right but somehow the key in the UI has it all mixed up.

Comment: At this point I can see that some are orange "reference edges", but sometimes there are double headed grey edges. What's the difference between double headed grey edges and orange reference edges?

Answer (score 0):

In the graph that you showed, it looks like only edges connected to the "read" operator are undirected ones - `dataflow edge`, however, you can temporarily disconnect the `read` node by right click and "Remove from the main graph". Then it turned out that the edges turned from dataflow edge (undirected) to reference edge (directed), which does not make that much sense.

We probably need to count on someone who really understood javascript to figure out how this works by looking at the source code of [tensorboard](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tensorboard/components).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hmmm. That is weird. At least some of those new "reference" edges are actually references to something (not that that helps interpret the docs much, but at least the word "reference" now seems motivated).